# adding a pie chart by using the embedded data

Tags: javascript

I have three embedded data ED1, ED2, ED3 in my survey. They are numbers generated by math operations. I want to use those embedded data to show the respondents a pie chart based on the calculated embedded data values.

Could you help me how can i do that by using JavaScript in Qualtrics.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add javascript libraries to Qualtrics by either embedding it in your template (preferred) or the html for one of your questions.  From there, it's matter of selecting your preferred charting library (e.g., chart.js), linking it to your template, pulling your embedded data variables, and letting your selected library work it's magic.

The details are going to depend on which library you select.